# Get current post id outside the loop. Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a plugin for wordpress. And the problem is that, how can I get the current post ID outside the loop?

I have a button on the post, and the `post ID` should be returned when the button is clicked by the user.

So, do anyway to get the post id?

My plugin dir: `wp-content\plugins\updateDatabase\js\connectionDatabase.php`

Here is my code: And my url `http://localhost:8080/wordpress/?p=1169`

```
        $post_id = $_GET['p'];
        echo $post_id;
        $link = getConnection();

        $bonusPoint = 0;

        $query_sql = "SELECT bonus_point FROM post_data03 WHERE post_id =" .$post_id;
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query_sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $bonusPoint = $row['bonus_point'];
                }
       } else {
                  echo "0 results";
       }
```

---

Using `$post`:

```
function getBonusPointFromDataPost()
{
        global $wp_query; 
        global $post;
        $post_id = add_action( 'the_post', 'get_post_info' );
        $link = getConnection();
}
```

`GetBonusPointFromDataPost()` will be fired when the user clicks the button which on the post page. And at the same time, the `$post_id` should be returned.

And I make a function to return the `$post_id`, but it only work when I add the `action` to it.

```
function get_post_info() {
        global $wp_query;

        global $post;
        $post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;
        echo $post_id;
        return  $post_id;
    }
```

How can I return the `$post_id` when the user clicks the button.

Comment: $postId = $_GET['post'];

Comment: I am trying to use this method, but I found out that the `url` doesn't have the `post` - `http://localhost:8080/wordpress/2016/08/03/1147/`

Comment: Go in setting->Permalink,  check which option you selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is,
use `global $post` to get the current post object

```
global $post;
echo $post->ID;
```

Comment: I don't why, but it doesn't work. I will update my question.

Comment: I tried it when I add `add_action`, and it is work. But when I try it in my function, It doesn't work, because my `function` doesn't do with the `add_action` and it is outside the `Wordpress loop`. Do there have some way to get the `post id` outside the loop? thx